# how to enhance ebean models in a jar

Tags: ebean, playframework-2.4

i have this requirement to factor out the ebean models of a
project so they can be reused by other play projects. i thought about creating a
subproject containing only the models, but then that means i have to duplicate the
subproject in every project that depends on it which isn't DRY enough to me. so
then i created a jar of the subproject using publishLocal so the main project now
just includes it like any other library in the build.sbt file. everything compiles well
but when i run the main project i get this exception
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Bean class module.models.User is not enhanced.
how do i make sure the models in the jar are enhanced?

Answer (score 0):

Probably best to use compile time enhancement. For example, the maven enhancer.

Refer: http://ebean-orm.github.io/docs/setup/enhancement#maven

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.avaje.ebeanorm</groupId>
    <artifactId>avaje-ebeanorm-mavenenhancer</artifactId>
    <version>4.8.1</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>main</id>
        <phase>process-classes</phase>
        <configuration>
          <packages>org.example.domain.**,org.example.anotherdomain.**</packages>
          <transformArgs>debug=1</transformArgs>
        </configuration>
        <goals>
          <goal>enhance</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```