# Odd reference to com.avaje.ebean.bean.EntityBean in ebeans

Tags: java, sbt, ebean, playframework-2.5

I have an odd error I'm encountering when trying to run an application. Here's the situation, I have a project (lets call it Project A) that has entities that are referenced in a second project (Project B). In order to prevent duplication of effort, bundled the referenced entities from project A in to a jar (call it project_a_models.jar) which I then drop into the lib folder of project B and run the application and get the following

```
[info] Compiling 12 Scala sources and 31 Java sources to /mnt/Storage1/Projects/kodi/target/scala-2.11/classes...
[error] /mnt/Storage1/Projects/kodi/app/controllers/KodiController.java:18: cannot access com.avaje.ebean.bean.EntityBean
[error]   class file for com.avaje.ebean.bean.EntityBean not found
[error]         List<PersonRole> personRoles = (List<PersonRole>) Secured.getPerson(ctx()).getRoles();
[info] /mnt/Storage1/Projects/kodi/app/util/Util.java: /mnt/Storage1/Projects/kodi/app/util/Util.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
[info] /mnt/Storage1/Projects/kodi/app/util/Util.java: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
[error] (compile:compileIncremental) javac returned nonzero exit code
[info] Compiling 12 Scala sources and 31 Java sources to /mnt/Storage1/Projects/kodi/target/scala-2.11/classes...
[error] /mnt/Storage1/Projects/kodi/app/controllers/KodiController.java:18: cannot access com.avaje.ebean.bean.EntityBean
[error]   class file for com.avaje.ebean.bean.EntityBean not found
[error]         List<PersonRole> personRoles = (List<PersonRole>) Secured.getPerson(ctx()).getRoles();
[info] /mnt/Storage1/Projects/kodi/app/util/Util.java: /mnt/Storage1/Projects/kodi/app/util/Util.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
[info] /mnt/Storage1/Projects/kodi/app/util/Util.java: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
[error] (compile:compileIncremental) javac returned nonzero exit code
[info] Compiling 12 Scala sources and 31 Java sources to /mnt/Storage1/Projects/kodi/target/scala-2.11/classes...
[error] /mnt/Storage1/Projects/kodi/app/controllers/KodiController.java:18: cannot access com.avaje.ebean.bean.EntityBean
[error]   class file for com.avaje.ebean.bean.EntityBean not found
[error]         List<PersonRole> personRoles = (List<PersonRole>) Secured.getPerson(ctx()).getRoles();
[info] /mnt/Storage1/Projects/kodi/app/util/Util.java: /mnt/Storage1/Projects/kodi/app/util/Util.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
[info] /mnt/Storage1/Projects/kodi/app/util/Util.java: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
[error] (compile:compileIncremental) javac returned nonzero exit code
[error] application -
```

Person and PersonRole are entities in project A that are used in project B. 
As you can see from compilation error, it's referencing 'com.avaje.ebean.bean.EntityBean' instead of the io.ebean version.
I'm using Play 2.5 with ebeans to run both the applications and have the following in their plugins.sbt

```
// The Play plugin
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.5.12")

// Web plugins
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-coffeescript" % "1.0.0")
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-less" % "1.1.0")
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-jshint" % "1.0.4")
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-rjs" % "1.0.8")
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-digest" % "1.1.1")
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-mocha" % "1.1.0")
addSbtPlugin("org.irundaia.sbt" % "sbt-sassify" % "1.4.6")
addSbtPlugin("io.teamscala.sbt" % "sbt-babel" % "1.0.5")

//addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-gzip" % "1.0.0")
//addSbtPlugin("com.github.stonexx.sbt" % "sbt-babeljs" % "1.0.5")

// Play enhancer - this automatically generates getters/setters for public fields
// and rewrites accessors of these fields to use the getters/setters. Remove this
// plugin if you prefer not to have this feature, or disable on a per project
// basis using disablePlugins(PlayEnhancer) in your build.sbt
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-play-enhancer" % "1.1.0")

// Play Ebean support, to enable, uncomment this line, and enable in your build.sbt using
// enablePlugins(PlayEbean).
 addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-play-ebean" % "4.0.0-M2")

//sbt plugin for eclipse
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbteclipse" % "sbteclipse-plugin" % "5.1.0")
```

and this in their build.sbt (they are largely similar)

```
name := "Project_A"
version := "1.0"

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayJava, SbtWeb, PlayEbean)

scalaVersion := "2.11.8"

JsEngineKeys.engineType := JsEngineKeys.EngineType.Node

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  javaJdbc,
  cache,
  javaWs,
  "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.27",
  "commons-io" % "commons-io" % "2.5" withSources(),
  "org.webjars" %% "webjars-play" % "2.5.0-4",
  "org.webjars" % "react" % "15.3.1",
  "org.webjars.npm" % "react-dom" % "15.0.1",
  "org.apache.poi" % "poi" % "3.14",
  "org.apache.poi" % "poi-ooxml" % "3.14",
  "org.webjars" % "jquery" % "3.1.0",
  "org.apache.pdfbox" % "pdfbox" % "2.0.3",
  "org.webjars" % "highcharts" % "4.2.5",
  "org.webjars" % "material-design-icons" % "3.0.0",
  evolutions,
  "javax.mail" % "mail" % "1.4.7",
  "be.objectify" %% "deadbolt-java" % "2.5.3"
)

resolvers += Resolver.url("Typesafe Ivy releases", url("https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases"))(Resolver.ivyStylePatterns)

fork in run := false
```

So my question is, where is the reference to 'com.avaje.ebean.bean.EntityBean' coming from ? is there a way I can clean up my dependencies and plugins to make sure that the right ebeans version is being used? Any insights would be really helpful.

Comment: You may have some problem with the dependencies (error points to `com.avaje.ebean.bean.EntityBean` but your `sbt-play-ebean`plugin is `4.0` that uses ebean with the new packages name `io.ebean` ) and/or the [enhance beans](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33891272/how-to-enhance-ebean-models-in-a-jar)

Comment: That is correct, I want to use 4.0 and in essence get rid of `com.avaje.ebean.bean.EntityBean` and use `io.ebean.bean.EntityBean`. I've cleaned out my repo cache and rebuilt it but I still keep getting references to `com.avaje.ebean.bean.EntityBean` in the compiled entity classes

Comment: Go back to version `3.1.0` for the ebean plugin. Could it be a problem on how did you add the dependency for your second project on your main project. I guess you have to declare the decency on SBT instead of a jar. You should edit the post and add the tag sbt, to me it looks like a problem on SBT and not a problem on play.